# Issues accessing MySQL on Raspberry Pi (3 & Zero) through ESP8266

Tags: mysql, mariadb, raspberry-pi3, esp8266, raspberry-pi-zero

not sure whether this is the right place to open this topic, but I'll give it a try.

Recently I am experiencing an unexpected behavior on my (two) Raspberry Pi´s (one is a raspberry Pi 3 B and on a Zero).

I tried out the following configurations:

1. The RasPi Zero is connected via eth0 to the Router. It opens a WiFi with its wlan0 (refer to: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md).

a. If I connect a Laptop or an ESP8266 NodeMCU to the "Home Wifi" both can access the MySQL (MariaDB) database.

b. If I connect a Laptop or an ESP8266 NodeMCU to the "RasPi Wifi" only the Laptop can access the MySQL (MariaDB) database. The ESP82866 connection to database is "blocked" but no error message.

I made a sketch you ca refer to: [Configuration 1 (with RasPi Zero)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1v3j.png)

2. The RasPi 3 is connected via wlan1 to the Router. It opens a WiFi with its wlan0 (refer to: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md).

a. If I connect a Laptop or an ESP8266 NodeMCU to the "Home Wifi" both can access the MySQL (MariaDB) database.

b. If I connect a Laptop or an ESP8266 NodeMCU to the "RasPi Wifi" only the Laptop can access the MySQL (MariaDB) database. The ESP82866 connection to database is "blocked" but no error message.

see my sketch: [Configuration 2 (with RasPi 3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgaDj.png)

Who has experienced the sam issue? For my understanding it makes no sense that the Laptop (MacBook Pro) can access the database connected to any network via Python and als with phpmyadmin. The ESP can only connect to the database when it is in the "Home Network" The code running on the ESP is always the same except the SSID and the IP address of the MySQL Server).

Thank you. 
Alex

Comment: Can you ping the database from the server that cannot connect? Also in MySQL users can be authorized according to their IP addresses; you'll need to make sure the IP of the client is allowed by the `GRANT`.

Comment: Trying to ping the RasPi Zero from the ESP8266 gives me a time out (`Request timed out.`). But pining from Laptop works. Also `iptables -L -n` gives: `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination  ` But overall I guess the issue is more on the Raspberry Pi level rather than on MySQL level.

Comment: Is the MySQL db on the Pi? I.e if you are successfully accessing the db on the PC that its hosting this is likely a grant permissions issue on the db (local vs anyhost).

Comment: Yes the MySQL db is hosted on the Pi. So from the PC I can access it from both networks in both configurations. The Pi is also pingable from the PC (both networks). Only the ESP8266 has the issue to ping and access it from the "Pi opened WiFi" (192.168.4.1 - Network). In `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`I added already `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`.

Comment: I just tried out some pinging: The ESP8266 NodeMCU can `ping` the Raspberry Pi if it is the the "Home Network" (`192.168.188.0`). When it is in the "Pi own Network" (`192.168.4.0`) it neither can `ping` the Pi (192.168.4.1) nor the Laptop (192.168.4.2). But from the Pi and the Laptop a 'ping' to the ESP8266 NodeMCU (192.168.4.69) works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out a lot of workarounds and other ideas to get rid of the issue. Like to share some experiences I made (and unfortunately can not understand 100%).

1. If an ESP (tried out the NodeMCU, WemosD1 mini and ESP12F) is connected to a WiFi which is provided by the Raspberry Pi thru `hostapd` it cannot ping/access any device inside this network. I do not understand why, because any other device (e.g. RasPi or Laptop) can ping the ESP.
2. BUT the ESP can connect to a device outside it's own network. E.g. it can ping the second IP dress of the RasPi.

In my example the ESP receives the IP `192.168.4.96` (DHCP from RasPi with `hostapd` provided by the `wlan0`). It can Ping the `wlan1` of the same RasPi with IP `192.168.188.37`.

With this little success the ESP can than access to the Database on the RasPi. (After following the hint from [The Impaler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6436191/the-impaler) - using `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;`).

The main question still is open: Is there an explanation and solution to the initial issue I am facing - no access to the Database / any other device within the network the ESP is connected to?